# How to convert from strides to shape?

Tags: arrays, numpy, pytorch

In numpy or pytorch, how would I write a function that convert strides to shape?

The function to convert shape to strides, assuming left-to-right order, is:

```
def shape_to_strides(strides):
    strides = [1]

    for s in reversed(shape):
        strides.append(s * layout[:1])  # size of preceding subdimension

    # Remove the final element of layout, which is equal to len(t)
    return tuple(reversed(strides[:-1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that this is valid only if the array is a contiguous array.

The `strides` of a n-D array `arr`, are the N numbers such as `arr[i₁, i₂, ..., iₙ]` is at address `address of arr[0,0,...0] + i₁×stride₁ + i₂×stride₂ + ... + iₙ×strideₙ`.

In other words, `strideₖ` is the number of bytes separating `arr[i₁,i₂,...,iₖ,...,iₙ]` and `arr[i₁,i₂,...,iₖ₊₁,...,iₙ]`

So, if you have a bunch of contiguous numbers, which are supposed to be read in "C" order (that is in the order you would iterates them with n nested loops `for i₁ in range(shape₁): for i₂ in range(shape₂):... for iₙ in range(shapeₙ)`, then the strides may appear as a redundant information, since you can deduce entirely strides from the shape and the size of number.

`strideₙ` is what separates 2 consecutive elements on the last axis. That is, that is the size of a number. For example 8 for `float64`.

`strideₙ₋₁` is what separates 2 consecutive elements on the (n-1)th axis, that is, that is the size of one "line", that is that is, the number of elements in that line, times the size of an element. That is that is `shapeₙ×strideₙ` = `shapeₙ×sizeof(number)`.

`strideₙ₋₂` is what separates 2 consecutive elements on the (n-2)th axis. That is that is the size of one "layer". That is that is the number of lines in a layer, times the size of a line. That is `strideₙ₋₂ = shapeₙ₋₁×strideₙ₋₁`.

So, for example for an array containing all the RGB float64 values of a 1920×1080 image (shape 1080×1920×3, size of data=8).
`strides` is the triplet `(stride₁, stride₂, stride₃)` such as `stride₃` is what separates 2 consecutive color component of the same pixel (for example, what separates component G of pixel at yx=(100,200), and component B same pixel at (100,200)). That is, that is the size of the `float64`. That is `8`. So `stride₃=8`

`stride₂` is what separates 2 pixels (2 columns). So, for example what separates address of component R of pixel at yx=(100,200) and component R of pixel at yx=(100,201). So that is 3×8=24, since there are 3 float64 components per pixel. That is `stride₂=shape₃×stride₃=3×8`

`stride₁` is what separates 2 rows. Since 1 row is W=1920 pixels, each pixel is 3 float64, and a float64 is 8 bytes, that is 1920×3×8=46080. Which is indeed what `stride₁=shape₂×stride₂ = 1920×24` gives.

So, so far I've only explained what you already know, since you already wrote the "shape 2 stride" code. But I wanted to be sure it is clear why it is like that. And also, that future readers (since SO answers are supposed to be useful also for future readers) are at the same point.

Now

1. You may have notice that `shape₁` has never been used in the computation. Which means that what ever `shape₁` is, the strides are unchanged. In other words, no way to compute `shape₁` from the strides, since it has nothing to do with the strides
2. That is true only if all data are consecutive. My RGB image example gives frequent counter examples: it is not rare to see images organized with some alignment at the end of each row, so that each rows starts with an address that is a factor of 8. In my example, since components are float64, that is necessarily the case already. But, for example for a 100×100 uint8 RGB image, there are 100 pixels per rows, that is 300 numbers, so 300 bytes. But 300 is not a factor of 8. 304 is. So it may be preferable, for a 64 bits machine, to "waste" 4 bytes per rows, to ensure each rows starts at a multiple of 8. In such case, shape of array is (100,100,3), and strides is (304, 3, 1), not (300,3,1) as the formula would suggest

2bis. Just another scenario: that image could be just a RGBA image, in memory (4 bytes per pixel, so 400 bytes per rows, so 400000 bytes altogether), presented as a RGB image, so a (100,100,3) shaped array, with strides (300,4,1). That just skips the `A` channnel transparently.

2ter. If you look in SO (for example in the answers I gave, since that is one function I use often), you'll many usage of `np.lib.strides_tricks.as_strided`, for example to create sliding windows. Or of `np.transose`. Or `.reshape` or `[np.newaxis]` or `.moveaxis`, or `[::-1]` or... all those functions or pieces of code act by tuning the strides: no data is altered, but the strides is, so that the array appears to have another shape, while still referring to the same memory. In none of such cases (so, not even the very frequent `.reshape` or `[::-1]`) the stride can be deduced from the shape. And therefore the shape cannot be deduced from the stride neither.

3. There is a reason why both metadata exist anyway. If it were possible to compute one from the other, then it would be redundant.

All that being said, in the particular (and quite frequent, but again, contrary is not even rare; any result of .reshape, or .T is a counter example) case where we are just contemplating a contiguous bunch of data, for which your `shape2stride` is valid, then, you can get all but the first element of shape from stride like this

```py
def stride2shape(a):
    return (-1,)+tuple(a.strides[i]//a.strides[i+1] for i in range(len(a.strides)-1))
```

The returned shape starts is a -1 for the first axis size, since that is the axis we cannot guess. But after all, if the plan is to use `.reshape` on it, one `-1` is still ok.

For example

```py
import numpy as np
a=np.array((1,2,3,4,5), dtype=np.int16)
# a strides is, in reverse order
# 2 (because int16)
# 5×2=10 (because line of 5 int16)
# 4×5×2=40 (because layer of 4 lines of 5 int16)
# 3×4×5×2=120 (...)
# 2×3×4×5×2=240
# See
a.strides
# (240, 120, 40, 10, 2)

# Which allows to deduce the number of elements on the last axis
# it is the size of a line of last axis, divided by the size of 1 element = 10/2 = 5
# And the number of lines on the axis before (it is the size of one layer divided by the size of a line, that is 40/10=4)
# etc

stride2shape(a)
# (-1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

But no way the find the `-1`. That information is simply not there. Unless you know the total size of the array (in which case, it is `total size of array / stride[0]`)